# There are no $f,g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$, entire end $e^{f(z)}=e^{g(z)}+c$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to prove Picard's little theorem. Here are my steps:

> If $a,b\notin Im(\phi(\mathbb{C}))$ then $\phi_1(z)=\phi(z)-a$ and $\phi_2(z)=\phi(z)-b$ don't vanishes any where. then there are entire functions $f,g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ such that $\phi_1(z)=e^{f(z)}, \phi_2(z)=e^{g(z)}$. Then we have: $$e^{f(z)}+a=e^{g(z)}+b$$

Which gives title function equation.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Ju'x Finding all f,g with the statements. In other word prove that f=g &  c=0.

Comment: Actually, you don't want to find such $f,g$, you want to prove such $f,g$ don't exist. The title is wrong. Also, always put a question in body of the question, don't refer back to the title.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If I'm not sure that there is no solution, then what should I do?

Comment: True, but it is pointless to ask, "find a solution," when Picard's theorem shows that such a solution doesn't exist, and Picard's theorem is what you are trying to prove. You are not trying to find a solution, but quite the opposite, so an unsuspecting/uninitiated reader might spend a lot of time looking for a solution to something you ought to know (assuming your math books are not misleading you) does not exist.

Comment: You forgot to prohibit constant $f,g$

Comment: Why these steps? You just decided to follow some route, got stuck, and are now asking to complete it? Why do you think this method of proof will work out?

Comment: @SteveD exercise 11 chapter 5 of complex analysis Stein obtain the theorem in case of finite order and in that case it's hint was like my work. After exercise it explain the theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis, Theorem 13.11.

Comment: Could you give the statement of the theorem?

Comment: It is too long to copy at here. But it states if both $f$ and $1/f$ are holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$, then there is $g$ which is holomorphic and $f=e^{g}$.